# An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have Java EE Eclipse Indigo installed and am trying to use Help->Install New Software to install the SpringSource Tool Suite from the update site http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7

I have java 1.7.0_45 installed in use by Eclipse.

When I click "Finish", the Installing Software progress indicator displays and it goes about 49% of the way to completion before getting

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.grails.ide.eclipse.core,3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE.

Error reading signed content:C:\Users\BARRET~1.REE\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3011079682847967573.jar

An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\BARRET~1.REE\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3011079682847967573.jar

The last 3 lines are duplicated for around 20 different artifacts/jar files.
In my C:\Users directory, I have both a BARRETT~1~REE\AppData\Local\Temp directory and a barrett.reed\AppData\Local\Temp directory.  It looks like the files are being downloaded to barrett.reed\AppData\Local\Temp.  Perhaps that is the issue?  Any way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance,
B.J. Reed

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on my machine and created an issue for that: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3988.

Comment: As a workaround, you could install the 3.5.0 version of STS/GGTS, that seems to work fine: http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.5.0.RELEASE/e3.7